# swift: How to call modal view BEFORE action?

Tags: swift

When button is pressed, i want to show modal view with text input and confirm button, and then use the text that user wrote in action. What happens now - action is called, and only then the view is shown.

```
saveTrack.addTarget(self, action: "Save", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

func Save()
{
    mapController.doStuff()
}
```

How to make modal view pop first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a new modal view to your story board and segway to it when your action is called. On the modal view you can go back to your origin view or continue to your target view using the data from the modal view.